# How get length of Navigation Mesh?

Tags: python, coordinates, blender

I have a navigation mesh (as shown in the attached picture). The navigation mesh consists of curve and array modifiers. As it is has an array modifier, it consists of strings of planes (I see it when I switch to 'edit mode').

My question is, can I iterate over the navigation mesh to get its the length and coordinate of center of each small planes in the navigation mesh. If yes then, please give me some python based example. Thanks in advance!

[image: navigation mesh]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the small planes are the faces of the mesh, iterating through the polygons on the object mesh data provides access to the coordinates of the center of the face.

```
import bpy, mathutils

plane = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]
previous = None

for poly in plane.data.polygons:
  center = mathutils.Vector(poly.center)
  if previous:
    previous -= center
    #print length and center
    print(previous.length, center)
  previous = center
```